# StringBuilder initializer works one way in VS2015 but another in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, stringbuilder, visual-studio-2015

I have the following line of code, with works in VS 2015 and .Net 4.0, but I am getting an error in VS 2013.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("test") {[0] = 'T'};
```

Why it works in a different way?

Comment: ... because one is C# 6.0 and the other is C# 5.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, object initializer expressions don't support indexing in C# 5 (which is what VS2013 supports). This is a new feature in C# 6.

In C# 6, your code is equivalent to:

```
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(); // Compiler-generated 
tmp[0] = 'T';
StringBuilder s = tmp;
```

There's no single-expression equivalent of this in C# 5... although of course you can just use `new StringBuilder("T")` to achieve the same result...

The most *obvious* use case for this would be `Dictionary<,>` - but I'd argue that usually it's a better idea to use the "old style" object initializer syntax for that, which ended up calling `Add`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "key1", 10 },
    { "key2", 20 }
};
```

The indexer-based equivalent of that is:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    ["key1"] = 10,
    ["key2"] = 20
};
```

... but the disadvantage here is that if you supply two equal keys, the second will happily overwrite the first, as that's the behaviour of the `Dictionary<,>` indexer... whereas with `Add`, an exception will be thrown instead. Given that in an object initializer you almost *always* want to specify distinct keys, the `Add` approach gives more protection against bugs than the indexer approach.

Where this feature *will* be useful, however, is for types which have an indexer but no (working) `Add` method. For example, a fixed-length collection might well support element replacement but not addition.

For more details on the C# 6 language features, see the [Roslyn Codeplex site](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: Was writing exactly the same when your answer popped up :-)

Comment: Jon, as long as you're answering, could you provide a link to the new feature? And maybe something on a use case?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I don't know what there is in the way of links really - it's not like the C# 6 spec is out yet. I'll add a few notes though.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Have added a link to the Roslyn site, which is probably the most up-to-date source.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [a language feature of C# 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) called object initializer expressions which was supported in Visual Studio 2013, but not using the indexer.

Sample from the referenced page telling about this new C# 6 feature:

```
var cppHelloWorldProgram = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
  [10] = "main() {",
  [20] = "    printf(\"hello, world\")",
  [30] = "}"
};
```

This adds three items to the dictionary, having key 10, 20 and 30.

Comment: FWIW, the given example could be done in earlier versions as `{ 10, "main() {" },`, etc.

Comment: Now I'm picturing a line-numbered BASIC program with GOTO statements

Comment: @KooKiz: I have more a C++ feeling ;)

Comment: Object initializer expressions *are* supported... it's only the indexer part that isn't. Also note that the page you've linked to is pretty old now - some of the features discussed there have been dropped.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks. It is hard to write this clear. If you have any suggestions, you are welcome.

Comment: My suggest would basically be my answer :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: It is that I can't copy it... Well, if I do, can we copy your rep too? And maybe your desk too? ;)